# Moving from register to effective address

Tags: x86, nasm

I'm trying to move values from `al` and `bl` into effective memory, but I keep getting segmentation faults. What my program does is it takes the value located `[esi]` and `[esi+1]`, it then rotates these bytes and puts them back. However when putting them back `[esi]` and `[esi+1]` need to be swapped (so `bl` into `[esi]` and `al` into `[esi+1]`) and this is where I'm getting a segmentation fault.

```
mov al,  [esi]
mov bl,  [esi+1]
rol bl,4
ror al,2
mov [esi],bl
mov [esi+1],al
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why these segmentation faults are occurring?

My current complete code:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
        jmp short call_shellcode

decoder:
        pop esi
        xor ecx, ecx

        xor eax,eax
        xor ebx,ebx

        mov cl, 25

decode:

        lea edi, [esi]
        mov al, byte  [edi]
        mov bl, byte [esi+1]
        ror al,2
        rol bl,4
        mov byte [esi], al
        mov byte [esi+1],bl
        add esi,2
        loop decode
        jmp short EncodedShellcode

call_shellcode:

        call decoder

        EncodedShellcode: db 0x13,0x3,0x5,0xa1,0xf2,0xbc,0x37,0xa1,0x86,0xbc,0x26,0xa5,0xe6,0x26,0x3e,0x41,0x98,0x8b,0x35,0x26,0x1e,0xc2,0xb0,0x37,0x8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't have anything wrong. But because it fails on writing to `esi` but succeeds in reading `esi` it must mean that the destination address is valid, but write protected.

Most likely the value of esi is originated from .text segment, which is read-only.

An unlikely possibility is that the code segment is writable and that the esi points to the next instruction, which is then modified to contain an invalid instruction.

Comment: I'll post my complete code which I have at the moment, it's actually a piece of shellcode which uses the jump,call,pop technique

Comment: I think you are probably right, the .text section isn't writable probably

Comment: You can verify this by omitting `jmp short EncodedShellcode` and placing the Shellcode to `.data`. Then to overcome this issue the text segment must be reprogrammed as writable (through some system call) Check details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169417/self-modifying-code