# C - How can a pointer overwrite a local const block of memory but not the global const block of memory?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Last time I asked how can I generate `segmentation` fault in a program by bypassing the compiler's promise of not overwriting the `const` memory. User [Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli) described the following way, which worked perfectly.

```
const static int global = 123;

int main(void) {
  int *ptr = (int *)&global;
  *ptr = 456;

  // or, equivalent
  const int *ptr2 = &global;
  *(int *)ptr2 = 456;
}
```

Either way I was able to generate segmentation fault.

- ```
  int *ptr = (int *)&global;
  *ptr = 456;
  ```
- ```
  const int *ptr2 = &global;
  *(int *)ptr2 = 456;
  ```

Now my question is what is it that is preventing the pointer from writing to a `global const` block of memory but not to the `local const` block of memory. For example, in the below code I was able to write to the `const` block of memory without any issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const int local = 123;
  
  int *ptr = (int *)&local;
  *ptr = 456;
  
  // how come this be possible?
  printf("%d\n", local); // -> 456

  // or, equivalent
  const int *ptr2 = &local;
  *(int *)ptr2 = 512;

  // how come this be possible?
  printf("%d\n", local); // -> 512
}
```

I'm curious about knowing how this happened. Please enlighten me.

If it matters, I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`.

Comment: What happens to this "block" when your program terminates - is irrelevant and is not related to compiler. The two programs have nothing in common and the run of the first one should not impact the second one in any way. This memory is reclaimed by OS. To the question of overwriting `const` - it is a bad idea in general. It is `const` for a reason, and is not supposed to be changed.

Comment: you are right a *cosnt* block is not supposed to change but what if I want to make that move is it possible? Can I make the OS to reclaim that block of memory during the runtime of the program.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to store into memory that's declared `const` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You're asking several different, unrelated questions here.  The main point is that physical memory in one process is completely independent of physical memory in any other process (assuming you're not doing an explicit [mmap()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)).  You might want to read more about the difference between physical and logical memory spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory.

Comment: Can you explain me how the OS reclaim that memory after the termination of the program?

Comment: When a process starts, it gets virtual memory assigned to it. When the process ends, the virtual memory is removed.

Comment: So I'm asking whatever the memory type is if it's Physical, Logical, Virtual or whatever it is, Is there's any way so that I can overwrite the ```const``` block of memory created by our program.

Comment: **What are you trying to do?** Hack something? Modify others program data under its feet? Something else?

Comment: Yes Eugene Sh I'm trying to modify other pograms data can you help me doing so?

Comment: @Barmar if system does not have virtual memory?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Other than embedded systems, I don't think you're likely to encounter any.

Comment: @Ayush OS will not let you. You will need to find a way of getting the proper priviledges and then access other program memory.  But it will require many years of learning and practicing

Comment: @Barmar I do "encounter" embedded systems every day at work :) as it is my daytime job.

Comment: @Ayush You can do it using the `ptrace()` mechanism.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Or do this stuff under old plain MS-DOS :)

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I'm not a microcontroller programmer so I could be wrong, but I don't think they have multiple processes with independent memory. They're usually non-hosted implementations, so many of the normal OS concepts don't apply.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but it was not multitasking except pop-pups residing in the memory :)

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland You mean "was not" - yeah. But resident program could very well intervene in the foreground program. I remember killing my Norton Commander this way, makin a resident screen-saver :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. old good times :)

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that I think it's gonna answer my question.

Comment: I've reworded your question to make it more clear, also adding your comment from below my answer.

Comment: A `const`-qualified variable may be allocated in a read-only segment, and if its address is never taken no storage for it may be allocated *at all* (its value will be encoded directly into the machine code).  In that case, no, you definitely can't overwrite it.  That depends on the system, of course - all `const` means is that the compiler should issue a diagnostic if the `const`-qualified variable is the target of an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

> after the termination of the program what exactly happens to that block?

What happens to the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) of your process is decided by the operating system. When the program terminates, the operating system will wipe out any memory that was allocated for your program, regardless of what that memory was being used for. The concept of `const` has nothing to do with this.

> Was the compiler able to remove that const qualifier from that particular block? Can I be able to overwrite that block of memory, if so how can I do that explicitly?

You cannot change how a variable was declared. It stays that way for its entire lifetime. You won't be able to do this, and even then, it's [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) to try doing it.

> What if I need to overwrite a `const` block of memory? Is there any way to do that?

If you need to do this, the logic of whatever program you are writing is flawed. You cannot, and should not do this. It is undefined behavior, and in the best scenario will kill your program with a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

---

Ok, if you really want to kill your program with a segmentation fault caused by writing to a `const` variable, *assuming that your compiler puts global `const` variables in a read only section (e.g. `.rodata`)*, then the following should suffice:

```c
const static int global = 123;

int main(void) {
    int *ptr = (int *)&global;
    *ptr = 456;

    // or, equivalent
    const int *ptr2 = &global;
    *(int *)ptr2 = 456;
}
```

You need to "cast away" the `const` qualifier in order for the compiler to not treat it as an error. Again, this only works if the compiler puts `global` into a read-only section (which is not required by the standard). If this does not cause a segmentation fault, then this means your compiler does not put all `const` variables in read-only sections.

Comment: Yes Marco exactly this is what I'm trying to say I want to kill my program with a *segmentation fault* how can I do so. If I try writing to read-only memory it will simply raise an error but I want to kill the entire program with a segmentation fault during runtime.

Comment: @Ayush hmm ok, added an example.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it but I'm not getting it correctly although I know the concepts of pointers, multi-level pointers, static scope and whatever you have used in your code but why are you trying to dereference the same memory block two times, when you already have written to that memory block once so what's the need of writing it again.

Comment: @Ayush read my comment, it's just a different way of doing it. It's an example, you don't need to to id two times.

Comment: I think I need to play with this a few more times in order to get a better understanding, I'll ask you if I'll get stuck somewhere. Well thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely up to the implementation. For example, `const` data on bare metal ARM uCs is stored in the FLASH memory. You can write to there but it will have no effect at all.

Hosted systems will behave differently depending on the OS, its version and hardware.

***`How can I overwrite a const block of memory`*** simply if you want to write do not declare it `const`. If you do respect the promise given to the compiler.

If it is just curiosity of the beginner, there is no other way than experimenting. Experiment, debug and try to interpret the result.

EDIT.

In most common implementations:

- constant local (automatic variables are created on the stack which is not protected by the operating system against writing - you are not getting the segfault.
- constant global (static storage) variables are placed in the `.rodata` segment which is protected by the operating system against writing - you are getting the segfault.

Comment: You're not wrong, and you bring up the important use case that the "memory" in question might not be virtual memory at all.   BUT .... the OP clearly has some fundamental misunderstandings about "memory" in general, and about the C/C++ programming construct "const" in particular.  It's probably most imperative to make sure the OP does some reading, and better understands more of the "basics" before he/she can correctly interpret "experiments".  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I updated my question. Could you please tell me how this happened?

Comment: @Ayush see the updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to identify such implementations? Why such implementations even exists if it violates the basic design of `const` specifier?

Comment: @Ayush it is undefined behaviuor - anything may happen. Your understanding of it is very limited. Simply remember - never invoke undefined behaviours by doing similar things.

Comment: @0___________ Could you please help me improve my question? This is my only question that has -3 votes and I want to improve it please help me....